# Prepared statement with Match AGAINST search has no result in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I can't get any result with this one in Laravel 8

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('?*' in boolean mode)",[$q]);
```

If I do this it works

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('test*' in boolean mode)");
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use quotes round a bind variable, so you need to alter the value you bind to have the extra content...

```
AGAINST(? in boolean mode)",[$q."*"]);
```